# How make patch in PHPStorm suitable for Drupal.org?

Tags: community-official-site, version-control

PHPStorm will create patch in this form:

```
Index: core/modules/node/templates/node-edit-form.html.twig
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- core/modules/node/templates/node-edit-form.html.twig    (revision 4652b443e9f89734487e225fb76829595b5239a1)
+++ core/modules/node/templates/node-edit-form.html.twig    (revision )
@@ -1,6 +1,8 @@
 {#
 /**
  * @file
+ * Default theme implementation for a node edit form.
+ *
  * Two column template for the node add/edit form.
  *
  * This template will be used when a node edit form specifies 'node_edit_form'
```

After I export it I always have to remove the header and add the a/.. and b/.. prefixes and convert to LF so it'll look like this:

```
--- a/core/modules/node/templates/node-edit-form.html.twig
+++ b/core/modules/node/templates/node-edit-form.html.twig
@@ -1,6 +1,8 @@
 {#
 /**
  * @file
+ * Default theme implementation for a node edit form.
+ *
  * Two column template for the node add/edit form.
  *
  * This template will be used when a node edit form specifies 'node_edit_form'
```

Is there a way to export patch that I can directly use for drupal.org?

Comment: I don't get the close vote on this.  PHPStorm is a tool used for Drupal, so this is on-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHPStorm patching issues have a long history. I have corresponded with their staff more than once, about a year ago. They told me then, that my issue was taken up to developers, but never actually corrected it. Right now, PHPStorm issues patches incompatible with Drupal.org, and we can do nothing about it.

To create a working legit patch, you need git, and create a patch like this:

`git diff > patch_name.patch`

See http://drupal.org/node/707484

A number of PHP Storm request related to this issue have been merged into a single issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92793

Comment: Is this PHPStorm's fault or does Drupal.org have special requirements for patch format?

Comment: PHPStorm's. Drupal.org uses a standard git patch format.

Comment: I couldn't find any issues in the phpstorm issue tracker for this so I went ahead and created an issue for it. Please go vote for this issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23407

Comment: I got an update today from the tracker. It seems they are still doing something with these issues - they seem to have united them now http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92793

Comment: Yeah, I searched and searched, but their search sucks, so I created a new issue, and then it got marked as a dupe of your original. So upvote Alexei's issue